# Not getting the Assignment Posted by a particular teacher

Tags: laravel, eloquent

In my QuestionController, i am trying to get all assignment posted by a particular user so as to attach that question to that particular assignment, also that the user only sees the assignment he/she posted in a drop down, but it doesnt work.
here is the code in my create method:

```
public function create(Teacher $teacher)
    {
        $assignments = Assignment::where('teacher_id', $teacher->id)->get();
        $quizzes = Quiz::orderBy('created_at', 'ASC')->get();

        return view('questions.create', compact('assignments', 'quizzes'));
    }
```

and here is my view code:

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="assignment_id" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Assignment') }}</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <select name="assignment_id" id="assignment_id" class="form-control">
            <option value="null">Please Select</option>
                @foreach ($assignments as $assignment)
                <option value="{{$assignment->id}}">{{$assignment->name}}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
            <pre>Please choose this only if this question is for an Assignment</pre>

        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you check if `$teacher` variable has a value?

Comment: Please post the code of your routes file and try to execute `dd($teacher)` and check the attributes.

Comment: when i dd($teacher) i got this error Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo::$id

Comment: public function create(Teacher $teacher)
    {
        $teacher = Auth::user()->teacher()->id;
        dd($teacher);
        $assignments = Assignment::where('teacher_id', $teacher->id)->get();
        $quizzes = Quiz::orderBy('created_at', 'ASC')->get();

        return view('questions.create', compact('assignments', 'quizzes'));
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Teacher.php model class put the below method of one-to-many relationship

```
public function assignment()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Assignment'); or
    return $this->hasMany('App\Assignment','teacher_id', 'id'); 
}
```

And You get Assignment posted by that Teacher as

```
public function create(Teacher $teacher)
{
    $assignments = $teacher->assignment()->get();
    $quizzes = Quiz::orderBy('created_at', 'ASC')->get();

    return view('questions.create', compact('assignments', 'quizzes'));
}
```

Comment: this is good, but it solve the error but still doesnt get the assignment posted by the eacher, it just returns an empty array

Comment: this is good, but it solve the error but still doesnt get the assignment posted by the eacher, it just returns an empty array

Comment: what is your foreign_key name in Assignments table? you need to have teacher_id in assignments table or if field name is differ check the edited asnswer

Comment: whats going to be value of local key

Comment: the primary key of Teachers table like id